# Zynq7000 PS DMA "Done" Signals Too Soon

Tags: xilinx, zynq

TL;DR: The Zynq7000 PS built-in DMA returns a "Done" signal too soon. It seems to signal as soon as it has (I assume) filled its internal "MFIFO" and no longer needs access to the data source. But my SW needs to know when it has actually finished transmitting the data as well.

Does the PS DMA have a status bit to indicate whether the transmission has finished? The Xilinx documentation is unclear on a few of those DMA registers 
(http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf, page 276)

I'm using the DMA to pump a chunk of data from DDR memory over to a PL IP, using the following C code:

```
// Allocate memory in DDR, 1600 bytes PLZ.
char *mem_block = malloc(1600*sizeof(char));

// Fill memory with data (not shown)

// Configure the DMA command
memset(&dmaCmd, 0, sizeof(XDmaPS_Cmd));
dmaCmd.ChanCtrl.SrcBurstSize = 1;
dmaCmd.ChanCtrl.SrcBurstLen = 4;
dmaCmd.ChanCtrl.SrcInc = 1;
dmaCmd.ChanCtrl.DstBurstSize = 1;
dmaCmd.ChanCtrl.DstBurstLen = 4;
dmaCmd.ChanCtrl.DstInc = 0; // Do not increment, (Fixed DST Addr.)
dmaCmd.BD.SrcAddr = (u32)mem_block;
dmaCmd.BD.DstAddr = (u32)0x43c10000; // Destination address (in PL)
dmaCmd.BD.Length  = 1600; // Bytes
```

I then start the DMA transfer...

```
status = XDmaPs_Start(&dmaInst, 0, &dmaCmd, 0);
if (status != XST_SUCCESS) {
    printf("ERROR, could not start DMA Txfer.");
    return XST_FAILURE;
}
```

And wait for it to complete, before reading back a result from my IP.

```
while (!(Xil_In32(XPAR_PS7_DMA_S_BASEADDR + XDMAPS_INTSTATUS_OFFSET) & 0x00000001)) {
   i++; // Waiting for DMA to finish...
}
result = Xil_In32(0x43c10004); // read result from my IP 
// Result is available as soon as DMA is finished--on the very next 100MHz fabric clock.
```

The problem I'm having is that this result is often read back too soon, before the data transfer was completed. Apparently, the DMA sometimes says it is done while the DMA transfer is still ongoing (I can tell because, from chipscope, I can see the read occurring while the write bursts are still happening).

How can I set my software up to wait until the DMA is *actually* done with the data transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation was well-camouflaged, but I found just what I was looking for.

As I was typing this question I realized there must be some status bits in those DMA channel registers.. Turns out, there is actually a Channel Status register for each channel, the lower 4-bits of which represent a state of the channel. (I had to dig into Appendix B of their documentation to find it, page 1201 of the document linked in the question). This 4bit state is 1001 ("Completing") when the DMA has triggered a DONE but is still transmitting data, and goes to 0000 ("Stopped") when the channel is actually done.

Xilinx even provides a handy macro in their auto-generated BSP to get the offset for each channel's status register address: `XDmaPs_CSn_OFFSET(n)` where `n` is channel number--0 in my case.

My Fix was just to change my while loop to check for the state of the channel to go to 'Stopped', signaling a completed transfer.

```
while (!(Xil_In32(XPAR_PS_DMA_S_BASEADDR + XDmaPs_CSn_OFFSET(0) & 0x0000000F) != 0x00000000) {
    // Wait until done
    i++;
}
// Now DMA is truly, really done transferring data.
// get real result
result = Xil_In32(0x43C10004); // Read from my IP
```

Hope this can save someone some time & frustration! :D

Comment: Thank you. Faced exactly the same problem and your answer makes everything clear